# Qt QGraphicsScene is not accessable from QGraphicsView (on Qt 5.6.1)

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I am new to Qt. I am trying to catch mouse press and release in a `QGraphicsView` area and draw a line. to do this, I extended `QGraphicsView` and called it `myQGraphicsView`. It seems that the scene is not attached properly since I added a "*Hello World*" and it never appears in the View. Here is the code for my extended class:

```
class myQGraphicsView : public QGraphicsView
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:

myQGraphicsView(QGraphicsScene *scene, QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR) : QGraphicsView(scene,parent){
     //  QGraphicsView::QGraphicsView(scene,parent);
}


 QPoint *pointPtr, *startPos,*endPos;
 QGraphicsView *cv;//MAA
 QGraphicsScene *c;
 QGraphicsScene *scenePtr; // MAA
protected:
void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) {

      show();

}

void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) {
    // pos is wrt widget. Global is wer to global screen
    qDebug()<<" Mouse pressed at "<<QWidget::mapFromGlobal(event->globalPos()); //globalX();
    startPos = new QPoint;
    startPos->setX(QWidget::mapFromGlobal(event->globalPos()).x());
    startPos->setY(QWidget::mapFromGlobal(event->globalPos()).y());

}

void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event) {
   qDebug()<<" Mouse relase pressed at x="<<event->globalPos().x()<<" y ="<<event->globalPos().y();
   endPos = new QPoint;
   endPos->setX(QWidget::mapFromGlobal(event->globalPos()).x());
   endPos->setY(QWidget::mapFromGlobal(event->globalPos()).y());
   c->addLine(0,0,50,50);
   update();
}

void mouseMoveEvent ( QMouseEvent * event )
{
  //Show x and y coordinate values of mouse cursor here
  qDebug()<<"X:"<<QString::number(event->x())<<"-- Y:"<<QString::number(event->y());
  endPos = new QPoint;

}


}
```

It seems that the mouse gets detected and the right methods are called. However, neither "*hello world*" nor the line gets drawn in the view. I tried `cv1->setScene` on the view and that did not do anything either.

So I declared a 2nd view pointer called `cv2` and that is using the `QGraphicsView`. All the information seems to work fine there and it gets drown. I read through the posting and it seems they were suggestion of setting event filters so I added that to both views (`cv1` and `cv2`). the event filter simply returns `false` for all events ( which should be the default behavior from documentation). It did not do anything.
Here is the code snippet in great.cpp for the `cv1` and `cv2`. notice that in `cv1` (`mymyQGraphicsView` instance), I created a pointer to the scene (called `c`) and gets assigned `c1` so I can `addLine` to it.

```
        c1 = new QGraphicsScene(0,0,500,300,this); 

    text= c1->addText("Hello, world!");

    text->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable);
    text->setVisible(true);
    cv1 = new myQGraphicsView(c1,this);
    cv2= new QGraphicsView(c1,this);
    KeyPressEater *keyPressEaterPtr = new KeyPressEater(this);
    cv1->installEventFilter(keyPressEaterPtr);
    cv2->installEventFilter(keyPressEaterPtr);
    cv1->c =c1;

    layout = new QGridLayout;
    layout->addWidget(topLabel,0,0);
    layout->addWidget(wellCoord,1,0);
    layout->addWidget(cv1,1,1,1,-1); <-view is added to a great class
    layout->addWidget(TimeStepGroup,2,0);
    setLayout(layout);
```

Finally, here is great.h:

```
 myQGraphicsView *cv1;//MAA
 QGraphicsView *cv2;//MAA

 QGraphicsScene *c1; // MAA 
 public:
 void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) {
    // MAA

    cv2->show();
  }
  protected:

  void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) {

    qDebug()<<"gridwell Mouse pressed at "<<QWidget::mapFromGlobal(event->globalPos()); //globalX();
    startPos = new QPoint;
    startPos->setX(QWidget::mapFromGlobal(event->globalPos()).x());
    startPos->setY(QWidget::mapFromGlobal(event->globalPos()).y());
    QWidget::mousePressEvent(event);

}
void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event) {

    qDebug()<<"gridwell Mouse released at x="<<event->globalPos().x()<<" y ="<<event->globalPos().y();
   QWidget::mouseReleaseEvent(event);
    endPos = new QPoint;
   endPos->setX(QWidget::mapFromGlobal(event->globalPos()).x());
   endPos->setY(QWidget::mapFromGlobal(event->globalPos()).y());

   lineItemPtr = c1->addLine(startPos->x(),startPos->y(),(endPos->x())- (startPos->x()),(endPos->y())-(startPos->y()) );
   lineItemPtr->setVisible(true);
   cv2->update();
}

void mouseMoveEvent ( QMouseEvent * event )
{
  //Show x and y coordinate values of mouse cursor here
  qDebug()<<"gridwell X:"<<QString::number(event->x())<<"-- Y:"<<QString::number(event->y());
  endPos = new QPoint;

}
```

Finally, here is the `keyEater` which I cut and pasted from the documentation:

```
class KeyPressEater : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
 public:
  KeyPressEater(QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR) : QObject (parent){
  }

protected:

  bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
  {

    return(false); // propagates events
  }
};
```

Any ideas why `cv1` does not get the scene `c1` ( since it does not print even "*hello world*". but `cv2` does?

Thanks for your help!

update: I did more investigation and changed the following routine:

```
 void myGraphicsView::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event) {
   qDebug()<<" Mouse relase pressed at x="<<event->x()<<" y ="<<event->y();
   endPos = new QPoint;
   endPos->setX(event->x());
   endPos->setY(event->y());


      c->addLine(0,0,event->x(),50);


 }
```

Now, when I click inside cv1 view area, I see the line in cv2 since both cv2 and cv1 views are pointing to the same scene (cv1->c = c1; line in great.cpp). This proves that Scene is not mapped correctly in cv2 since not even the "Hello World" shows up. I am baffled since that seems to be a simple object being passed to the constructor as shown in many examples.

Comment: You can show how you used `setScene()`, also please show only the necessary code, if you want to provide all your code to test it, I can do it through github, drive or similar.

Comment: Another question I have is because you override the `paintEvent()` method and also call the `show()` function.

Comment: code shown is minimal. the only extra code is showing how I am including the view in the layout. In all examples I have seen, they use the main so I was wondering if that points to anything.. The setSense is used as follows but to no avail: cv1->setScene(c).

Comment: I was doing cv1->show in the great.cpp routine and that was not working. I searched a little and there was a posting that said it works only if you put it in the paintEvent. So I did.

Comment: How strange, you can tell me the link of this publication to consult the author of that answer. I could help you if you provide me your complete code through github, drive, dropbox, etc since I see big errors in your code.

Comment: I send you an email a tf  e.yllanescucho

Comment: Share a code that can be compiled with the .pro and main.cpp